# Query string type field in MongoDB

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a json string stored in a document in format of

```
{
 "alert":"{\"UploadTimeStamp\":xxx,\"PDID\":\"xxx\",\"Alerts\":[{\"Timezone\":330,\"AlertType\":\"OverSpeed\",\"Data\":{\"Latitude\":\"10.9\",\"Longitude\":\"43.44\",\"MtrsPerSec\":\"125.5\"},\"TimeStamp\":1499346345164}]}"
}
```

how do i get specific fields like UploadTimeStamp, Latitude,Longitude ?

i tried using `db.collection.find({},{alert:1,_id:0})`

and it displays alert dictionary like above but when i try to access `alert.UploadTimeStamp` i get null result. This is the cmd that i used

`db.collection.find({_id: ObjectId("xxx")},{"alert.UploadTimeStamp":1})`

Comment: What you're trying to achieve by coming up with above json rather than this normal looking one: `{
 "alert": {
  "UploadTimeStamp": "xxx",
  "PDID": "xxx",
  "Alerts": [{
   "Timezone": 330,
   "AlertType": "OverSpeed",
   "Data": {
    "Latitude": 10.9,
    "Longitude": 43.44,
    "MtrsPerSec": 125.5
   },
   "TimeStamp": 1499346345164
  }]
 }
}`

Comment: I would like to extract specific fields instead of querying all fields and export into a csv file

Comment: Please clarify whether I can use modified collection posted above

Comment: i quite didn't understand what you expect from your question. But i would like specific ways to extract certain fields in a embedded document.

Comment: Weird, I'm getting results properly, is that what you need? https://i.imgur.com/v7Jgje5.png

Comment: { "alert":"{\"serverTimeStamp\":\"22-xx-18 09:53:15 PM\",\"Alerts\":[{\"NameMapping\":{\"Vehicle\":[{\"name\":\"xxxx\",\"pdid\":\"xxxx\"}]},\"AlertType\":\"Idle\",\"Timezone\":19800000,\"Data\":{\"alertType\":\"Idle\",\"Latitude\":\"23.22222\",\"Longitude\":\"-78.22222\",\"IdleStartTime\":1521735554950,\"IdleEndTime\":1521735739042},\"Timestamp\":1521735795937,\"Name\":\"rr rrrrr- Engine Idling. Please switch off the engine.\"}],\"PDID\":\"44rreeeewdgff\",\"UploadTimeStamp\":1521735795937}","alertType":"Idle","alertState":"Open","createdAt":{"$date":"2018-03-22T16:23:23.682Z"},"PDID":"2213"}

Comment: post exact data document @SandeepRamesh

Comment: the above is one record

Comment: Are you using shell? @SandeepRamesh Just wondering why you are posting json string

Comment: ya i am using shell.

Comment: @RahulRaj used the same like in image, i got null

Comment: shell should return something like this. `{
  "UploadTimeStamp": "2018-03-28T10:53:14.687-0700",
  "PDID": "1212",
  "Alerts": [
    {
      "Timezone": 330,
      "AlertType": "OverSpeed",
      "Data": {
        "Latitude": "10.9",
        "Longitude": "43.44",
        "MtrsPerSec": "125.5"
      },
      "TimeStamp": 1499346345164
    }
  ]
}`

Comment: mongos> db.collection.find({_id: ObjectId("xxxxx")},{"alert":1})

Output:
{ "_id" : ObjectId("xxxx"), "alert" : "{\"UploadTimeStamp\":122334,\"PDID\":\"22334dd\",\"Alerts\":[{\"Timezone\":330,\"AlertType\":\"OverSpeed\",\"Data\":{\"Latitude\":\"23.665\",\"Longitude\":\"12.6644\",\"MtrsPerSec\":\"125.5\"},\"TimeStamp\":1499346300165}]}" }

Comment: any luck people ?

Comment: can we see a screenshot? @SandeepRamesh

Comment: i am not allowed to

Comment: I am suspecting your data for alert is of type string which is a json. Is that right?

Comment: I best thing to do is to fix your data.

Comment: i think its of array

Comment: it says valid json in data validator

Comment: @Krishna alert is of type string. so what do i do now ?

Comment: I dont think it is possible. Lets see if anyone comes up with solution

Answer (score 0):

You can get by using .(dot)
e.g.

```
 db.dc1.find({},{"UploadTimeStamp":1})
```

OR

```
db.collection.find({},{"Alerts.Timezone":1})
```

OR

```
db.dc1.find({},{"Alerts.Data.Latitude":1, "Alerts.Data.Longitude":1})
```

Your JSON is like below:-

```
db.dc1.insert({
  "UploadTimeStamp": "2018-03-28T10:53:14.687-0700",
  "PDID": "1212",
  "Alerts": [
    {
      "Timezone": 330,
      "AlertType": "OverSpeed",
      "Data": {
        "Latitude": "10.9",
        "Longitude": "43.44",
        "MtrsPerSec": "125.5"
      },
      "TimeStamp": 1499346345164
    }
  ]
})
```

[image: POC of the query]
Thanks
DC

Comment: sadly i am getting null when i used your query

Comment: 1. First you need to insert the data in mongo db 2. then you can execute the commands. The collection name her I have given indc1, you can give whatever name you like.

Comment: i am directly querying from a db. i do have data

Comment: Please share the query you are executing.

Comment: db.coll.find({_id: ObjectId("xxxx")},{"Alerts.Data.Latitude":1})

output:  { "_id" : ObjectId("xxxx") }

Comment: Try this, with no filter >> db.coll.find({},{"Alerts.Data.Latitude":1});                              With filter condition >>  db.coll.find({"PDID": "1212"},{"Alerts.Data.Latitude":1});

Comment: @SandeepRamesh Your data is misleading. I am able to query as per the structure you mentioned. Please review your data and question asked. Thanks

Comment: @Krishna can u please share the queries used. let me try the same